# Static method returns null

Tags: php

I'm trying to make class which returns html. I'm wondering why my class return null. If I echo the result in the class it works correct, but if I try to return it, the result is NULL

This is my class

```
<?php
Class HTML {
public static function create( $fuction_tag, $params ) {
    HTML::$fuction_tag( $params );
}

public static function ul( $params ) {
    if ( ! is_array( $params['content'] ) ) {
        $params['content'] = [ $params['content'] ];
    }
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <ul class="<?php echo $params['ul_class']; ?>">
        <?php foreach( $params['content'] as $content ) : ?>
            <li class="<?php echo $params['li_class']; ?>">
                <?php echo $content; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
    $result = ob_get_clean();

    return $result;
}
}
```

And here I'm call it in another file :

```
 <?php dd(HTML::create('ul', [
'ul_class' => 'ul',
'li_class' => 'active',
'content' => 'test'
])); 
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `create` function doesn't properly return the value it obtains:

```
public static function create( $fuction_tag, $params ) {
    return HTML::$fuction_tag( $params );
}
```